# Bluejeans on 32bit Scientific Linux

Tags: scientific-linux, plugin

My OS is Scientific Linux 32 bit. I can only find plugins for 64bit. Is there a plugin for 32bit?

Comment: Red hat based systems mostly prefer 64bit. I don't think there are many 32 bit plugins for any Red Hat based OSes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about [this BlueJeans](http://bluejeans.com/), I would direct my question to their BlueJeans Community for confirmation as to whether there's a 32-bit plugin available for Linux.

- https://community.bluejeans.com/bluejeans

Searching there I found a few tickets that related to 32-bit. The first one pertains to [NPAPI Browser Plugin](https://community.bluejeans.com/bluejeans/topics/npapi-browser-plugin) technology. Depending on whether BlueJean requires this or not, will be problematic if you're attempting to use Chrome. Chrome recently dropped support for NPAPI.

The other ticket, [chrome plugin won't run on Chrome x64](https://community.bluejeans.com/bluejeans/topics/chrome-plugin-wont-run-on-chrome-x64), makes me think that the plugin is actually 32-bit, and you might be running into some other issue.

One of BlueJean's employees replied as follows to the 32-bit/64-bit inquiry in that ticket:

> Hi Margaret - I am sure you saw our Customer Success Engineer's
>   response on the other thread but wanted to repost here just in case:
>
> Hi Margaret,
>
> Chrome x64 is on our dev teams radar.  Please stay tuned on a
>   supported date for this feature.  I will also add you to the feature
>   tracker request.